# Change all children's image source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a need to change the src of all the Images found within an UL element. I do have a Jquery library so maybe that will make it easier. The HTML looks like this.

```
<ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <img id="aImg" alt="sortable image" src="images/a.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <img id="bImg" alt="sortable image" src="images/b.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <img id="cImg" alt="sortable image" src="images/c.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

What's the quickest method I could embody to rename all image sources to the same filename with a "-backup" before the file extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass a callback to `.attr()`:

```
$('ul img').attr('src', function(i, src) {
    return src.replace('.', '-backup.');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#sortable li img").each(function(){    
   this.src = this.src.replace(".jpg", "-backup.jpg");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li img').each(function() { 
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('\.jpg', '-backup.jpg') 
})
```